# Image features extraction

Tags: java, android, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a visual marker like [this](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/137/baruq.png) one and a blob detection algorithm in Java .. How can I extract the regions of the image so that I can run the blob detection algorithm on each one separately so that it can detect 1, 1, 3 blobs respectively.

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and where are you stuck? Do you want to detect the marker in some other image? Could you give an example of the image where you want to detect the marker? Which 1,1,3 blobs do you mean? As it is your question is unlikely to lead to useful answers.

Comment: The image I attached is the actual marker, but the marker has nested regions, inside it's black region. Such as the ears and face. Now I need someway to separate those nested regions so that I can run the blob detection algorithm on each of them separately. By running the blob detection algorithm on the right ear it should yield one, same thing for the left ear, and finally it should yield 3 for the face. So the output is 1, 1, 3

Comment: OpenCV's [cvFindCountours()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cvFindContours) seems to do what you want: It differentiates between external contours and holes (the internal contours) just like you want.. And we can call it from Java easily with [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a fun detection game. You will need a few morphological tools so as to solve it.

Since your goal is to detect valid d-touch pictures, you may want to organize your analysis differently. For example, with Mathematica:

[image]

Detecting whether a black region encloses at least 3 white regions by filling the holes of the image and counting the number of connected components:

```
Max@MorphologicalComponents[
        FillingTransform[DeleteBorderComponents@img]] >= 3
```

[image]

Detecting whether half of these white regions contain one or more black regions can be done by counting holes inside each white region:

```
comp = ComponentMeasurements[DeleteBorderComponents@img, "Holes"]; 
2*Count[comp, _ -> n_ /; n > 0] >= Length@comp
```

[image]

Detecting whether there are further levels of nesting can be achieved by querying for the number of enclosed components:

```
Count[
  ComponentMeasurements[DeleteBorderComponents@img, "EnclosingComponentCount"],
  _ -> n_ /; n > 0] == 0
```

[image]

Some of the operations above may be tricky to implement in Java. I shall pass on that one -- done with the fun part!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you need to accomplish.  The blob analysis itself should extract the "regions".  Classifying the contrasting dark objects or "blobs" in your target image should give you any target areas you need.  For example, the objects could be classified based upon some combination of size, shape, color, position, eccentricity, major/minor axis, child relationship to a parent blob, etc., then selected depending upon which features you are interested in.

Perhaps you need a more substantial blob analysis algorithm that returns more complex blob data.

Comment: Let me rephrase, then .. in the image I attached; 6 blobs will be detected: 1) The whole drawing 2) The dot in the right ear 3) The dot in the left ear 3),4),5) the eyes and the nose in the face. What I actually want is detecting each blob from 2) to 5) 
separately so that the output is 1 blob, 1 blob, 3 blobs.

To be more precise; these are the rules I'm trying to implement http://d-touch.org/design/rules/